# Using Django auth User model as a Foreignkey and reverse relations

Tags: python, django

I am using the `User` model from  `django.contrib.auth.models`. I have another model called `Post` which references `User` through a foreign key.

The problem is when I try to access a logged in user's posts through

```
request.user.post_set.order_by('-timestamp')
```

I get an error, `User` object has no attribute `post_set`. So how do I use the default auth model with foreign keys?

Comment: Unless you have some trivial error there, I once noticed that some specific "monkey patches" of User model lead to back references not being created.

Answer (score 17):

Have you included the application containing the Post model in your settings.py installed apps?

e.g.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'testapp'
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

and ran manage.py syncdb?

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

i.e does the database table for the Post model definately exist?

I did a quick test and found no problems:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PostModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

(test) C:\Users\Steven\django_projects\test\testproj>python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> test = User.objects.get(username='test')
>>> test.postmodel_set.all()
[]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Post.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-timestamp')
```

Comment: Good workaround, but those backreferences should be there, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

it may be caused by you defined related_name option in ForeignKey (or OneToOneField), if it's like this :

```
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='post')
genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

you should use it as below :

```
print(user.post.genre)
```

Or :

```
print(post.user.email)
```

Notice : if i can see your models.py and settings.py it would be better answer.