# Being able to have multiple items in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm making a system that keeps track of all the orders a customer orders looking at products, purchase date, price, etc.

If I want to be able to allow the user to, say, purchase more than one product...(i.e. 5, 20, 323523). How can I allow the user to add more products?

Here's the code I have:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    dollar_amount = models.FloatField()
    purchase_date = models.DateField()
    notes = models.TextField( null=True, blank= True)
```

I want it to where

When I'm at the add page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbcbd.png

I can add more than 1. Would this be a foreign key relationship? How would I go about implementing that?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/) says 'Also note the “Add Another” link next to “Poll.” Every object with a ForeignKey relationship to another gets this for free.'.

And personally, I would add a foreign key to user. Which the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458358/using-django-auth-user-model-as-a-foreignkey-and-reverse-relations) says to do by:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
...
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

That way, you know which products belong to which users.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a ForeginKey relationship between your ProductOrder and user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
   product = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   vendor = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   dollar_amount = models.FloatField()
   purchase_date = models.DateField()
   notes = models.TextField( null=True, blank= True)
   purchased_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Then you need add a custom Admin class in the admin.py:

```
class PurchaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = [..., 'purchased_by',...]
```

It should show up a groupbox that allow you to assign the purchase order to any existing user.